# sort in pipe does not work

Tags: awk, sed, sort, cut

I have many of those files and I would like to know what is the highest Memory consumption (Mem)

```
$ cat utg006012l-racon-2.fasta.o5230935
[racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded target sequences 0.013133 s
[racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded sequences 6.667809 s
[racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded overlaps 6.267742 s
[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=>                  ] 8.633518 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==>                 ] 9.058757 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===>                ] 9.490215 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [====>               ] 9.760396 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=====>              ] 10.008019 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [======>             ] 10.332580 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=======>            ] 10.681680 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [========>           ] 11.022209 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=========>          ] 11.350026 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==========>         ] 11.675731 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===========>        ] 12.004713 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [============>       ] 12.330591 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=============>      ] 12.650907 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==============>     ] 12.965631 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===============>    ] 13.271211 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [================>   ] 13.553430 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=================>  ] 13.825148 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==================> ] 14.088558 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===================>] 14.350089 s^M[racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [====================] 14.598578 s
[racon::Polisher::initialize] transformed data into windows 0.542441 s
[racon::Polisher::polish] generated consensus 11154.363114 s
[racon::Polisher::] total = 11183.003787 s

-----
PBS Job 5230935.pbs
CPU time  : 03:05:52
Wall time : 03:06:38
Mem usage : 4960216kb
```

I used `grep "Mem" *-racon-2.fasta.o*  | cut -d':' -f3 | sed 's|kb||'| sed 's|b||' |awk '{print $1}' | sort` but it did not sort the output

```
582384
5832
5832
584004
584552
584928
585008
585144
585416
586164
586252
587792
588196
588852
589204
58992
590336
590704
591184
592112
5928
5932
593700
59420
59476
595128
595696
596356
5968
59696
597772
599356
59972
6012
60300
6032
60404
604240
60528
6064
606544
607448
608080
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `sort` sorts lexically by default - you probably want `sort -n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cut -d':' -f3` will extract the 3rd `:`-delimited field from a line, but the line that you are applying it to looks like

```
Mem usage : 4960216kb
```

i.e., it only has two fields:

1. `Mem usage` , and
2. `4960216kb`.

To avoid that long-winded pipeline, you could instead use

```
sed -n '/^Mem/s/[^[:digit:]]*//gp' *-racon-2.fasta.o* | sort -n
```

This uses a single `sed` call to extract the lines that start with the string `Mem` and cuts out the number by deleting everything that isn't a digit on those lines.  It then passes the extracted numbers to `sort -n` for a numerical sort.

This would be equivalent to

```
grep '^Mem' *-racon-2.fasta.o* | tr -d -c '[:digit:]\n' | sort -n
```